# Terminal shows garbled characters with same settings as other terminal showing correct characters

Tags: terminal, tty, character-encoding, stty

I have vim setup with NerdTree on a remote machine. I have two local machines. When I ssh to remote machine from one of the local machines (say A), it displays all the symbols in NerdTree correctly. However, when I ssh from the other local machine (say B) to remote machine, those symbols show up as some garbled characters. I tried to do some search on this and tried various locale and encoding things I could find. Following are the settings of the two local machines and the remote machine.

Local machine A:

```
$ stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?;
ixany iutf8

$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8

$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Local machine B:

```
$ stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?;
ixany iutf8

$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8

$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The settings on local machines seem to be the same. Both of them run CentOS style OS. Both of the terminals are Gnome Terminals set to use character encoding UTF-8. Only difference I can see is machine A uses version 2.16.0 with font Courier and machine B uses version 2.31.3 with font monospace. So machine B actually uses newer version.

Remote machine:

```
λ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8

λ stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
-brkint ixany

λ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The `λ` symbol which is my `$PS1` on remote machine is displayed correctly on both terminals.

How do I proceed from here? Do the fonts installed on local machines matter?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. This looks like font problem. As soon as I installed the fonts from machine A to machine B, it started working fine.

To install fonts, I copied everything from `/usr/share/fonts` from machine A to machine B and then ran `fc-cache /usr/share/fonts` as described [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-x-fonts.html)